# How to check existence of multiple files(giving type extension as parameter) in a folder -using bash

Tags: bash, file, if-statement

Scenario:
I have a set of .txt files inside folder and script is checking whether *.txt files exists or not

Script:

```
set -x
if [ -f  *.txt ]
then
        echo exist
else
        echo not
fi
```

Output:

```
+ '[' -f 1.txt 2.txt ']'
test.sh: line 2: [: 1.txt: binary operator expected
+ echo not
not
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-f` unary primary takes only **one** operand. You need to replace `[ -f *.txt ]` with:

```
( set +f -- *.txt; test "$*" != '*.txt' || test -f '*.txt' )
```

This doesn't perform a type check on every matching file but I assume it'll suffice for your case.

- `+f` to set is for making sure pathname expansion is not disabled,
- `--` is for marking the end of options,
- `*.txt` expands to files matching `*.txt`, using this with `set` we're populating `$*` with them,
- if there is no file matching `*.txt`; it will not expand to anything, it'll stay the same; with `test "$*" != '*.txt'` we're checking if that's the case,
- there is one edge case where the only file matching `*.txt` is a file named `*.txt`; `test -f '*.txt'` is for covering that case.

---

As @Inian suggested, using Bash extension `nullglob` we could omit the last check. Like:

```
( shopt -s nullglob; set +f -- *.txt; test "$*" != '' )
```

---

However, **I think** the most advisable approach for this task is to use `find ... | read` as the condition:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*.txt' -type f | read
```

Comment: Yo man, you GEM of everything :) thanks for sharing nice solution. Could you please do add some explanation, so that guys like me can learn more from it, though I am able to make it out but if you could some info will be great, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 added a brief explanation, hope it helps